# Netty 4 : share handler in different pipeline

Tags: netty

The `ChannelInitializer.initChannel` method is called for every new connection,

```
pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast(new ServerWebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/api", "*", false));
```

Can I reuse the same instance for all connections? How to tell if specific handler is reusable cross multiple connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handler that you can reuse, is annotated with `@Sharable`, which means that is guaranteed stateless.

Just go ahead and check the documentation for the different handlers.

For example `HttpServerCodec` and `HttpObjectAggregator`are sharable.

The last handler is probably a custom handler that you've implemented, at least I'm not familiar with it. There it depends on your implementation.

And otherwise, you can just reuse the the first two handlers by making a static instance of them and recreate only the last handler for every connection.

Comment: Are you sure `HttpServerCodec` and `HttpObjectAggregatorare` are sharable? I checked the source code of them,  they are not annotated with ` @Sharable`

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/f6c16f4897ce395011c70c0351a0ddc3d6c21337/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectAggregator.java

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/83c349ffa94d3992c4ee511d3625afc0c97c12bb/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpServerCodec.java

Comment: Sorry, you are fully right. They are not shareable, because they themself don't use the annotation. I was mislead by the inheritance summary of the documentation, which only means, that the class knows about the annotation.

So non of the mentioned handlers are sharable, as they are all state full.